# How can I find an ID where the datetime field matches the datefield, but where another field is null?

Tags: django

I have a model for keeping track of an employee clock-in/clock-out app..

```
class ClockPunch(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    punch_in_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    punch_out_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    hours_for_the_day = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default="0.00", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date', ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

and 2 views, one for clocking in, and one for clocking out...

```
class ClockPunchInView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    context_object_name = "clock_punch"
    fields = ['punch_in_time']
    model = ClockPunch
    template_name = 'pages/layout.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.employee = self.request.user
        object.punch_in_time = timezone.now()
        object.save()
        return super(ClockPunchInView, self).form_valid(form)


class ClockPunchOutView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    context_object_name = "clock_punch"
    model = ClockPunch
    template_name = 'pages/layout.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        object = form.save(commit=False)
        object.employee = self.request.user
        object.punch_out_time = timezone.now()
        object.save()
        return super(ClockPunchOutView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and here is my actual form. I did it like this because I just wanted buttons users could press in the top navbar. I plan to make this more ajaxy later on...

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url 'administration:clock_in' %}'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" style="margin-right:6px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Clock-in"></button>
</form>
<form method='POST' action='{% url 'administration:clock_out' %}'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" style="margin-right:6px;" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clock-out"></button>
</form>
```

the clock-in works fine, but I need to somehow get the ID of the last clock-in for the clock-out view to know which line to update. How would I get the pk of the last clock-in with a blank or null value in the clock-out field? Thanks!

Update:
I'm gonna go about this a little differently since I'm having a hard time updating the last record without passing the pk though the url. I'm just gonna create a new entry every time and use the last 2 entries for the user to find the time delta.
I'm trying to write a method to only check-out the user if they're checked in, however its not working. The last entry does have a punched_in = True however its acting as if it does not so the problem must be with my form_valid method below

```
class ClockPunchOutView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
context_object_name = "clock_punch"
model = ClockPunch
fields = ['punch_out_time', 'punched_out',]
#form_class = PunchOutForm
template_name = 'pages/layout.html'
success_url = '/'

def form_valid(self, form):
    object = form.save(commit=False)
    last_entry = ClockPunch.objects.filter(employee=self.request.user).order_by("-punch_in_time").first()

    if last_entry.punched_in:
        object.employee = self.request.user
        object.punch_out_time = timezone.now()
        object.punched_out = True
        object.save()
        return super(ClockPunchOutView, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `ClockPunch` entry for that employee with the most recent `punch_in_time`:

```
object = ClockPunch.objects.filter(employee=self.request.user).order_by("-punch_in_time").first()
object.punch_out_time = timezone.now()
object.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, that does make more sense

Comment: I think i didnt really explain the problem very well.. when I click the clock-out botton I get the error "Generic detail view ClockPunchOutView must be called with either an object pk or a slug" since an UpdateView requires a pk to know which record to change. How would I pass the pk of the last sign-in through the url so that I could use it in the ClockPunchOutView?

Comment: I don't know, I never used this view approach. If you know the employee in advance, you can use the query in my answer to get the `ClockPunch` instance and have its `pk`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I have a feeling my approach to this probably isnt the best. Using 2 forms in my template seems like an ugly way to do it. I wanted to put 2 buttons (clock-in/clock-out) in my navbar thats in my layout.html that all other views extend from. What general approach would you take with this?

Comment: You can put your two buttons `in` and `out` in the your navbar and in one single view, detect which button was clicked. Then you know the employee from `request.user`. If it's a clock-in you create a `ClockPunch` entry and if it's a clock-out, you retrieve the last `ClockPunch` from that employee and fill the clock-out time (see answer to retrieve the `ClockPunch`).